# Rendering RMarkdown file using Python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, r-markdown, rstudio

I have a made a tkinter GUI for many users to use for live data collection. After the data collection, I would like a button that generates a summary file that I have created in RMarkdown because it makes very nice documents.

**This the RMarkdown file**

```
set.seed(123)
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)

plot(x, y, main = "Random Scatter Plot", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
```

**This is the python script**

```
import subprocess

command = ["R", "-e", "rmarkdown::render('test_rmd.rmd')"]
subprocess.run(command, check=True)
```

**When running the above script, I get the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hudak\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\hudak\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\reticulate\python\rpytools\subprocess.py", line 15, in __init__
    return og_Popen__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hudak\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\subprocess.py", line 808, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Users\hudak\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\subprocess.py", line 1164, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

**
When running the .Rmd file from the Anaconda command line I get this error:**

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
Execution halted
```